# Non null value associated with least value in other column

Tags: sql, netezza

My data is like this:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

I have tried using following SQL:

```
CASE 
    WHEN (MINDAY_DIFF > 0) AND (MINDAY_DIFF IS NOT NULL) 
        THEN FIRST_VALUE(BP_MED) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY MINDAY_DIFF ASC) 
END AS DRUG
```

This returns NULL.

I also tried

```
CASE 
    WHEN (MINDAY_DIFF > 0) 
        THEN BP_MED 
        ELSE NULL 
END AS DRUG
```

It returns both non-null values of `BP_MED`.

I also tried `NVL` but that didn't work either.

Since it is in Netezza. There are fewer solutions online. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The concept here is the following working inside out:

We didn't always have analytics to make things easier: So not knowing Netezza I took a more... antiquated approach.  There may be better/more efficient ways; which I would look for given a place to play around with; but I think this would work in most any RDBMS as I tried to avoid any RDBMS Specific aspects unless we're dealing with pre left join supported RDBMS.

- Find the Min ID and the day difference for that ID in a result set (MinAndID)
- LEFT Join back to the baseSet to get all possible values specifically to get BP_Med
- Then Join back to base Table to ensure we get ALL records and then populate only the BP_Med which links to the minDay_Diff.  Since it's a left join only 1 record per ID should return.

UNTESTED:

```
SELECT A.*, DesiredDrug.BP_MED 
FROM TABLE A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, Fill_Date, BP_MED, MinDay_Diff
           FROM TABLE BaseSet
           INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(MINDAY_DIFF) MDD, ID
                       FROM TABLE
                       WHERE ID is not null
                       GROUP BY ID) MinAndID
              on BaseSet.ID = MinAndID.ID
             and BaseSet.MinDay_Diff = MinAndID.MDD) DesiredDrug
 on A.ID = DesiredDrug
and A.Fill_Date = DesiredDrug.Fill_Date
and A.BP_Med= DesiredDrug.BP_Med
and A.MinDay_Diff = DesiredDrug.MinDay_Diff
```